# with my x64 Windows 7

Tags: server

ciao come faccio a fare un cd di ubuntu auto istallante con Brasero poi devo istallarlo in un pc con XP DOVE VORREI ISTALLARE UBUNTU E CANCELLARE TUTTO (XP COMPRESO)
GRAZIE

**Translation(using Google translate):**

hello how do I make a CD of ubuntu istallante car with Brasero then I have to install it in a PC with XP where I want to install Ubuntu and delete all (including XP). Thanks!

Comment: please translate.

Answer (score 0):

I would install it on a USB device. It's really easy to do, using the instructions at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install (instructions for DVD are listed there as well)

Translation (Google Translate)

Vorrei installarlo su un dispositivo USB. E 'davvero facile da fare, seguendo le istruzioni a http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install (istruzioni per il DVD sono elencati anche lì